# Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt error

Tags: java, installation, java-21

I am trying to set up an open source project but when I try to install the dependencies I get

`The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.`,

I have made sure I have Java in stalled since

```
→ which java
/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin/java
```

and I also set up the corresponding java environment variable in my bashrc rile

```
→ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Does anyone know what the issue may be? I am using MacOS and I installed java and jdk environment using homebrew if that provides insight. Also, this is the current version of java that I have

```
→ java --version
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have tried re installing java and jdk in homebrew but still getting same errors.

Comment: See linked question: The `apt` that the install script you are using is attempting to run is NOT the 'apt' that is producing the 'Unable to locate a Java Runtme' error - that install script is trying to use `apt` which is not gonna fly on a mac. Find another script.